# How do I make a loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a php array which writes `<div id="first_<?php echo $z; ?>" class="source">`

I'm trying to create a loop in JavaScript so I can change the `style.display` property of each. The total amount of `first_`s can be anywhere from 0 to 100.

All I know how to do is something like this:

```
function setup() {
    cow = document.getElementById('first_1');
    cow.style.display='none';
    cow = document.getElementById('first_2');
    cow.style.display='none';
    cow = document.getElementById('first_3');
    cow.style.display='none';
  }
```

My guess on how to do this would be something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    cow = document.getElementById('first_'var i);
    cow.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: remove var: cow = document.getElementById('first_' + i);

Comment: document.getElementById('first_'+i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
  var cow = document.getElementById('first_' + (i + 1));
  if (cow)
    cow.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: He said it could start at 0. This starts at 1.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - the poster said that the total "amount" (likely meaning "number") of items can be from 0 to 100. In his code he starts from 'first_1'.

Answer (score 1):

You use `i` incorrectly. You only use `var` when *declaring* a variable.

```
function setup() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.getElementById('first_' + i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You will want to make sure that the element you get exists so an exception isn't thrown. You do that by attempting to get the element, and if it is "truthy", set the `style.display` variable:

```
function setup() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('first_' + i);
        if (elem)
            elem.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

---

From what I read, you want to be able to provide a maximum. You can just add a parameter:

```
function setup(max) {
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        ...
```

Also, it sound like it can be from 0 to 100 *inclusive*. In that case, just change the `<` to `<=`:

```
function setup(max) {
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        ...
```

---

I would advise that this is bad practice and you should instead wrap the entire `first_1` through `first_100` block in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `i` incorrectly, only use `var` when you're declaring variables, not using them. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    cow = document.getElementById('first_' + i);
    cow.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE7 or older you can use [**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll), using a attribute selector and iterate through the resulting nodes, similar to this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="first_"]');

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1){
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

`querySelectorAll()` is supported in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari and IE8+ and allows you to specify any valid CSS selector.

The benefit here is that you don't have to know upfront how many elements you have as you simply create a collection of nodes dynamically which have an identifier starting with `first_` and iterate through that.

If you want to only select `div` elements starting with an id of `first_` you can also be more specific in your selector and use `document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="first_"]');`

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2NxC/) - Using `querySelectorAll()`

---